# Endpoint for user login/signup in Woocommerce Rest API v2

Tags: api, rest, woocommerce

I have searched completely in Woocommerce REST API documentation for the endpoint of user login/signup but unable to find it. Can anyone provide me the link to the endpoint and its documentation?

Answer (score 12):

You can achieve this in lot of ways.

**1st method is:**

It's not specific for WooCommerce but also for all WordPress login and sign up

---

**For sign up:**

Method POST

Params : username,email,password

https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users

It will create a new user

---

**For login:**

Method POST

Params : username/email,password

https://example.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token

It will generate an access token which you can pass in for your future requests.

You can use [JWT Authentication for WP REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) for login purposes

Comment: when I am passing email, password, it says username is required.

Comment: did you tried to pass your email id as username since wordpress accepts both logins

Comment: this one actually helped me. The plugin is what I needed. Thanks for this answer

Answer (score 3):

For reference:
Woocommerce users or customers are actually Wordpress users, more like blog subscribers (just like woocommere products are wordpress posts, so to create a user you could use WP_API functions for that purpose.

[wp_create_user](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user) To create users with minimum parameters (username, password and email).

[wp_insert_user](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user) To create users with extended user data.

I assume that user roles must match those that woocommerce handle ([customers or shop managers](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/roles-capabilities/))
Now there's also an endpoint for creating/updating/listing customers in WooCommerce REST API (http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#customers) but there's no login/auth support at the moment.

For login/authenthication there's [two mechanisms](http://wp-api.org/guides/authentication.html) in the WP_API: CookieAuth and OAuth
If you explain what you are trying to accomplish it would be easier to help.

Answer (score 2):

You can `create / signup` user by hitting `customers/` endpoint with params : `username` , `email` and `password`.

later you can insert more details like shipping or billing address by hitting `customers/<userid>`

Now, There's no endpoint available in the REST API for login customers but,

```
You can achieve this by:
```

- installing [JWT Authentication for WP REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) plugin in your WordPress admin.
- after installing this plugin, now you have the endpoint for login a customer

`https://yourdomain.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token?password=123456789&username=nicename`

> NOTE: it is recommended to use a username instead of email for login a customer because WordPress authenticates the user by the username.

- here's the last step: Don't forget to add `define('JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY', 'your-top-secrect-key');` in your `wp-config.php` file.