# How can I access the WooCommerce REST API from a react component rendered by a plugin? i.e. What to do with the API Keys?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-rest-api, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have a plugin that renders a react component to the client side in a way similar to the process described here:

https://developer.woocommerce.com/2021/11/15/how-does-woocommerce-blocks-render-interactive-blocks-in-the-frontend/

I need the rendered component to be able to make requests to the WooCommerce REST API, but I'm not really sure how to handle the authentication. My current set up  for development is like this:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "@wordpress/element";

const url =
    "https://my-website/wp-json/wc/v3/products?consumer_key=ck_123456789&consumer_secret=cs_987654321";

export default function Block() {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

    const fetchProducts = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: "GET",
            credentials: "same-origin",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "X-WP-Nonce": wpApiSettings.nonce,
            },
        });
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("Unable to Retrieve Data. Please try again.");
        }
        return response.json();
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchProducts()
            .then((data) => {
                setProducts((products) => [...data]);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(err.message);
            });
    }, []);

    if (!products.length) {
        return <div>loading</div>;
    }

    function strip(html) {
        let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html");
        return doc.body.textContent || "";
    }

    const items = products.map((prod) => (
        <li key={prod.id}>
            <img src={prod.images[0].src}></img>
            <h1>{prod.name}</h1>
            <p>{strip(prod.short_description)}</p>
            <h2>{prod.price}</h2>
            <button>
                {prod.button_text !== "" ? prod.button_text : "Add To Cart"}
            </button>
        </li>
    ));
    return <ul>{items}</ul>;
}
```

I've thought about somehow intercepting the request server side and setting the keys there, but I'm not sure how to do that or if that's the best approach.

What is the proper way to handle this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle authorization is with JWTs.

if your API endpoint has a user authentication function of some kind, you can send an API request with the username and password and you'll receive a session JWT in response.

You can then use the session JWT as the authorization key for your other REST requests.

[this post shows how to register users and login to get the JWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31364971/endpoint-for-user-login-signup-in-woocommerce-rest-api-v2)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Hopefully I can get that to work without everyone who visits the site having to create an account. As an alternative, would there be any downside in just creating a set of read only api keys that can be seen by end users and restricting access to certain endpoints?

Comment: I don't actually know woocommerce but I use the strapi API wrapper on a database for one of my projects, and in strapi you can configure database objects to be publicly viewable, meaning you don't need any api key in the REST request. This is done by modifying permissions for the "Public" role.

Is there something similar for woocommerce?

Comment: TBH, I'm in a similar boat as you are. I'm more familiar with fullstack JS stuff and got stuck working on a WordPress project. I do appreciate the feedback. AFAIK in WooCommerce there is only read, read-write, and write. for now, the best solution I can find is to generate keys as I mentioned above and then restrict access to sensitive endpoints in this fashion: https://www.createit.com/blog/woo-api-how-to-whitelist-endpoints/